# Clear Flutter sharedpreferences on macos

Tags: flutter, macos, sharedpreferences, userdefaults

I am using SharedPerefences plugin in Flutter in a macOS application, how can I clear shared preferences? Where are shared preferences stored on disk?
Default macos UserDefaults are stored in Library/Preferences, but seems Flutter saves somewhere else.

Comment: Do you want to specifically clear it manually?

Comment: Yes, sometimes I need to do it manually.

Comment: Please share an answer if you found a solution, Im struggling with this too

Comment: How can we clear it programmaticaly

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter, the SharedPreferences data is stored on the device in which the app is running. When you debug an app on macOS using an emulator, the SharedPreferences data is saved in the emulator's virtual file system.

Specifically, on macOS, the SharedPreferences data is saved in the following location:

```
~/Library/Containers/<App Bundle Identifier>/Data/Library/Preferences/
```

where  is the unique identifier for your app, as specified in your app's Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

On macos sharedprefs file is stored in a different place depending on the context :

- debug file is in: Library/Preferences/com.yourName.yourApp
- release file is in: ~/Library/Containers/com.yourName.yourApp/Data/Library/Preferences/